# StructureMap in ASP.NET Core doesn't handle primitives as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have this demo I use for demonstrating the various DI lifecycles in ASP.NET Core. It looks like this:

```
public interface IOperation
{
    Guid OperationId { get; }
}

public interface IOperationTransient : IOperation { }
public interface IOperationScoped : IOperation { }
public interface IOperationSingleton : IOperation { }
public interface IOperationInstance : IOperation { }

public class Operation : IOperationTransient, IOperationScoped,
    IOperationSingleton, IOperationInstance
{
    private Guid _guid;

    public Operation(Guid? value = null)
    {
        _guid = value == null ? Guid.NewGuid() : value.Value;
    }

    public Guid OperationId => _guid;
}
```

The demo uses a Web API controller to show the difference between DI lifecycles:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOperationTransient _transientOperation;
    private readonly IOperationTransient _transientOperation2;
    private readonly IOperationScoped _scopedOperation;
    private readonly IOperationScoped _scopedOperation2;
    private readonly IOperationSingleton _singletonOperation;
    private readonly IOperationInstance _instanceOperation;

    public ValuesController(
        IOperationTransient transientOperation, IOperationTransient transientOperation2,
        IOperationScoped scopedOperation, IOperationScoped scopedOperation2,
        IOperationSingleton singletonOperation, IOperationInstance instanceOperation)
    {
        _transientOperation = transientOperation;
        _transientOperation2 = transientOperation2;
        _scopedOperation = scopedOperation;
        _scopedOperation2 = scopedOperation2;
        _singletonOperation = singletonOperation;
        _instanceOperation = instanceOperation;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Dictionary<string, IOperation> Get() =>
        new Dictionary<string, IOperation> {
            { "Transient", _transientOperation },
            { "Transient2", _transientOperation2 },
            { "Scoped", _scopedOperation },
            { "Scoped2", _scopedOperation2 },
            { "Singleton", _singletonOperation },
            { "Instance", _instanceOperation }
        };
}
```

Using ASP.NET Core's built-in DI framework I wire the dependencies up like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingleton, Operation>();
services.AddSingleton<IOperationInstance>(new Operation(Guid.Empty));
```

This displays JSON that shows a different GUID for each of the two transient implementations on every refresh, the same value for each of the two scoped implementations which changes on refresh, the same value for the singleton which doesn't change on refresh, and always an empty Guid for the instance registration.

I wanted to show the same demo using [StructureMap's ASP.NET Core implementation described here](https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection).

Initially I registered my dependencies with StructureMap like this:

```
registry.For<IOperationTransient>().Use<Operation>().AlwaysUnique();
registry.For<IOperationScoped>().Use<Operation>().ContainerScoped();
registry.For<IOperationSingleton>().Use<Operation>().Singleton();
registry.For<IOperationInstance>().Use(new Operation(Guid.Empty));
```

But now when I run the app I see the following server exception:

> ArgumentException: Byte array for GUID must be exactly 16 bytes long.
>   Parameter name: b
>
> ```
> System.Guid..ctor(Byte[] b)
> lambda_method(Closure , IBuildSession , IContext )
> ```
>
> StructureMapBuildException: Error while building type System.Guid

I tried switching from using a `Guid?` to a `string` for my `OperationId` property and ran it again. This time I get the following exception:

> StructureMapBuildPlanException: Unable to create a build plan for
>   concrete type BuiltinDIDemo.Operation
>
> new Operation(String value) ┗ String value = Required primitive
>   dependency is not explicitly defined
>
> 1.) Attempting to create a BuildPlan for Instance of BuiltinDIDemo.IOperationTransient -- BuiltinDIDemo.Operation
>   2.) Container.GetInstance(BuiltinDIDemo.IOperationTransient)
>   3.) Container.TryGetInstance(BuiltinDIDemo.IOperationTransient)
>
> ```
> StructureMap.Pipeline.ConstructorInstance.ToBuilder(Type pluginType, Policies policies)
> ```

So how can I get StructureMap to handle `Nullable<Guid>`'s and primitives using defaults?

Comment: StructureMap can't inject a `Guid?`. For your demo, change `Operation` to have a default constructor and simply always create a new Guid, as follows: `public Operation() => _guid = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: Thanks, yes this is what I did to get the demo working, but I'm very curious to understand why StructureMap doesn't handle these types.

Comment: Well, I can't speak for StructureMap, but I can speak for Simple Injector, which contains behaves the same in this respect. With Simple Injector we explicitly decided *not* to allow null to be injected, because constructor dependencies should not be optional. And in this case we're talking about a (nullable) primitive. Primitives can typically not be injected automatically by your container using auto-wiring, as their type is ambigious. Example: what is the exact meaning of that `Guid`? Is it a customer id? Product id? It can be anything. It's better to be explicit, which is why SI blocks this

Comment: I expect the philosophy to be similar with StructureMap.

Comment: That certainly makes sense. I wonder why Microsoft decided not to apply that same philosophy with their built-in ASP.NET Core DI.

Comment: It’s hard to comment on the incentive of that particular feature, but I’ve experienced two driving forces (or design philosophies) that to have influenced the built-in container’s design the most, which are: 1) It’s designed first and foremost for the ASP.NET framework itself and third-party components, instead of targeting application developers first. 2) It tries to mimic the API of the Autofac DI Container.